# CSS Border only on certain div's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like to get a right side border for all div's except for the last in the row, where the row column count is variable via the bootstrap grid system dependent on device.

4, 3, 2 or 1 columns.

If I have 4 columns then only the first 3 would have a right border.
If I have 3 columns then only the first 2 would have a right border.
etc..

```css
rg-product-container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
}

.rg-product-container:nth-child(1n+1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
  <!-- ... More dynamically generated HTML -->
</div>
```

For reference I've created this photo, the CSS above renders a result like the image below. What I'm looking to eliminate is the red border as shown in the photo. Issue is it's variable based on the bootstrap grid.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap version 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outline` combined with `overflow:hidden` on the row can do it

```css
.rg-product-container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 30px;
}

.row {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude the last child of the row for border, you can simply use the `last-of-type` selector. Try this css code.

```
rg-product-container{
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    min-height:auto;
    padding:30px;
}
.rg-product-container {
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
.rg-product-container:last-of-type{
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Hello @Aryan thank you for the answer! It seems this works but it removes only the very last div in my stack not every 4th, 3rd, 2nd as per bootstrap grid system. So if I have a `<div class="row"></div>` with lets say 25 `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 rg-product-container">STUFF HERE</div>` then I would need every 4th div to have no border if viewed on a large screen, every 3rd div no border if on a medium screen, etc.. etc..

Comment: There is only 1 parent `row` div and then multiple `col` divs within it as they are dynamically generated dependent on how many products I have in my DB and that can change. My initial thought was I'd use media queries + a combination of some nth CSS but i've had no luck so far.